# how to detect if select2 has been loaded upon clicking the input field in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi is there a way to check if the select2 options has been loaded upon clicking the input field ? because what happening now is, when I click the input box, nothing happen even if the box got loaded, i had to click it the second time before something happens like e.g

```
$('form#myform .selection').click(function(){
     //how to detect if select2 option are loaded ?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the length property of the option selector for select2, you can use it the same way within the click event :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  console.log(" KAD : " + $("#kad").find('option').length);
  console.log(" KAD2 : " + $("#kad2").find('option').length);
  
  if($("#kad").find('option').length > 0)
  {
     // has options
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="kad"></select>
<select id="kad2">
  <option > 1 </option><option > a </option><option > b </option>
</select>
```